# right mysql structure for geo filtering

Tags: mysql

We are rearanging our database for home rentals and have following. We have different apis, where from the homes and apartments come and land. From apis we have only Country->Region->City(or village)  Structure mainly. Also we have apartments for 1 extra country where we have 
Region->City->City Part->Street  Structure

So we have made 2 mysql schemes. Could you critic a bit and maybe hint to  a better way? 
[image: First Sheme]

And Second one

[image: Second Scheme]

Could you please criticize and maybe give a better way to do the db, which will lead to better performance, less joins etc? We are not mysql experts :(((

Images are small for viewing here, so the links

[1st Scheme Image big one](http://gevork.ru/1.png)

[2nd Scheme Image big one](http://gevork.ru/2.png)

Comment: From a performance point of view it doesn't make *any* difference as long as you stick to the usual queries that you run against this structure. Use the model that fits your data best.

Comment: I would prefer using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model
for the places itself.

Comment: Nested Set? Hm... interesting idea @CappY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole schema is wrong! What do you know about database normalisation? Your schema doesn't match to requirements of 3rd normal form at least. 
For partical example:

You have countries:

```
-CountryName1
-CountryName2
-CountryName3
```

You have regions:

```
-RegionOfCountry1_a
 ...
-RegionOfCountry3_a
```

You have cities:

```
-City_1_Of_Country1_Region_a
 ...
-City_3_Of_Country3_Region_a
```

In example data in tree view will be:

```
-CountryName1
|_ -RegionOfCountry1_a
    |_ -CityOf_Country1_Region_a
       |_ -City_1_Of_Country1_Region_a
       |_ -City_2_Of_Country1_Region_a
       |_ -City_3_Of_Country1_Region_a
    |_ -CityOf_Country1_Region_b
       |_ -City_1_Of_Country1_Region_b
       |_ -City_2_Of_Country1_Region_b
       |_ -City_3_Of_Country1_Region_b
    |_ -CityOf_Country1_Region_c
       |_ -City_1_Of_Country1_Region_c
       |_ -City_2_Of_Country1_Region_c
       |_ -City_3_Of_Country1_Region_c
|_ -RegionOfCountry1_b
    |_ -CityOf_Country2_Region_a
       |_ -City_1_Of_Country2_Region_a
    |_ -CityOf_Country2_Region_b
       |_ -City_1_Of_Country2_Region_b
    |_ -CityOf_Country2_Region_c
       |_ -City_1_Of_Country2_Region_c
|_ -RegionOfCountry1_c
    |_ -CityOf_Country2_Region_a
       |_ -City_1_Of_Country2_Region_c
...
-CountryName2
|_ -SecondCountry
       |_ -MegaCityCountry3
...
-CountryName3
|_ -MegaRegionCountry3
       |_ -MegaCityCountry3
```

You have **houses** table which have a constraints of foreign keys **(country_id, city_id, region_id)** which "links" to these 3 tables. It give a possibility to create incorrect record Such as:

```
*name = "MyHouse with address data from a far galaxy"
country_id = CountryName**1**
region_id = RegionOfSecondCountry (from CountrName**2**)
city_id = MegaCityCountry3 (from -CountryName**3**)*
```

It means next: you don't know normalization requirements or you don't forecast transitive dependencies

Try to do next

```
----------------
Table "**houses**"
----------------
id
houseNumber
description
*fk_city_id*
----------------
```

*fk_city_id references to **cities**.id:*

```
----------------
table "**cities**"
----------------
id
name
*fk_region_id*
----------------
```

*fk_region_id references to **regions**.id:*

```
----------------
table "**regions**"
----------------
id
name
*fk_country_id*
----------------
```

*fk_country_id references to **countries**.id:*

```
----------------
table "**countries**"
----------------
id
name
----------------
```

P.S. >> Sorry for my bad English